# Ubuntu OS download consistently stuck at 0b/s

Tags: downloads

The download will start off strong (2.0mb/s or so, probably a server limit) and then quickly drop to 0b/s or something slow like 32kb/s. Then eventually the download will say something like: "unable to download" or text similar to that. Once I resume the download, it picks up speed and then plummets again.

Using the edge browser, up to date version of Windows.

Comment: Try a different mirror for the download.

Comment: Mirror? I'm downloading directly from the ubuntu site. I don't torrent.

Comment: Changed to a BC server, seems to be downloading consistently now. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: You may answer your own question, and accept it after a  bit, helping others and gaining some reputation in the process.